# Inflate context menu in a SherlockListFragment

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-listfragment

How to create a Contextmenu from xml in a `SherlockListFragment`. i know (see in the examples)

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    menu.add("One");
    menu.add("Two");
    menu.add("Three");
    menu.add("Four");
}
```

this work too for `SherlockListFragment` but i wanna inflate from a `menu/context_menu.xml`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after a while i found the solution

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    getSherlockActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
}
```